# What do you call the collection of all sets shattered by $F$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, discrete-mathematics, discrepancy-theory

The proof of [Pajor's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauer%E2%80%93Shelah_lemma) uses the collection of all sets $S\subseteq X$ shattered by some $F\subseteq 2^X$. Is there a standard term for the former object? I've been privately referring to it as the "shards" of $F$, inspired by the imagery of shattering.